# Upload в цикле

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема, как можно код запихнуть в цикл. Нужно что бы загрузка была не для одного файла как сейчас, а для одного и более. Если имеется то подкиньте пример пожалуйста!Заранее спасибо.

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
if(strlen($name))
{
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
{
if ($size < MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
{
$command=mysql_query("Insert into uploads(name) values ('$actual_image_name')");
$query=mysql_query("Select id,name from uploads where name='$actual_image_name'");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$id=$result['upload_id'];               
echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview' id='$id'>";              
}               
else
echo "Please select image..!";              
exit;
}
}
```

Comment: Попробовал засунуть в цикл но не помогло, загружалось только одно из выбранных изображений но сохранялось 2 раза

  
 for( $i = 0, $length = count( $_FILES['file']['name'] ); $i <   $length; $i++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно внутри формы создавать поля с квадратными скобками в конце. Т.е., так:

```
<form ...>
<input type="file" name="file[]">
<input type="file" name="file[]">
<input type="file" name="file[]">
...
</form>
```

Тогда $_FILES будет содержать массив и вы сможете легко его перебирать:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_FILES['file']['name']);$i++) {
    // Здесь обработка $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

проще 
foreach ($_FILES['file'] as $file) {
  // тут обработка $file['name']
}

вообще [Загрузка на сервер нескольких файлов](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.multiple.php), гуглится за 1 секунду